# Choosing a printer (with dialogue) to print a .xls file to

Tags: java, netbeans, printing, document, printers

I have to print a .xls file with a specified path on a network printer (but we have multiple network printers and I don't want to print it at the same one every time).
I have a GUI (programmed using NetBeans and the jExcelApi) with a "print"-button. When I click that button the printing dialogue should pop up where I can choose the printer I would like to print on and when I hit OK it should print it.
Is that possible, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

Without showing some of the source code you use for printing it is not really possible to give you an accurate answer...

the jExcelApi has `jWorkbook.showPrintDialog();` to do what you ask see http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jexcel/docs/JExcel-PGuide.html#AEN794

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it but it works only for workbooks that are embedded into the program... But I need to print a file that is on a network drive ("I:/Data/SuperSecretStuff/fileIwanttoprint.xls") and I just want to print it without importing it into the program again.